# Rest: url endpoint for extract similar data

Tags: rest

I have a REST syntaxe question:
what url do you give to an endpoint to extract data similar to the record which from the id passed?

By exemple : I have a class Record:
Record {id:12, phoneNumber:"+336746563"}

I want a endpoint who will return all the records who share the same phoneNumber than the record with the id 12

which url respect the most the REST protocol ?

EDIT IMPORTANT : the client DON't know the phone number when he call the url. only the 12 id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> what url do you give to an endpoint to extract data similar to the record which from the id passed?

Anything you want -- the machines don't care what spelling you use for your resource identifiers.

> I want a endpoint who will return all the records who share the same phoneNumber than the record with the id 12

```
/all-records-with-same-phone-number-as?id=12
/all-records-with-same-phone-number-as?12
/all-records-with-same-phone-number-as/12
```

All of these examples are *fine*.  They have different trade offs -- the first one is really easy to generate using an HTML form.  The last once allows you do interesting things with relative references and dot-segments.

```
/record/12/all-records-with-same-phone-number
```

similar to the above, we've just juggled the order of the path segments a little bit.  Might be useful if we want to have relative references to other resources under the same `/record/12` stem.

If you are expecting to need to paginate, then you might want to think about how the paging parameters fit with everything else.  Again, the machines don't care, but some spellings are easier to work with than others.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand the question but let me try.
You can do this in various ways which is best suited for you w.r.t. your programming language. For example, `domain.com/api/records/123456` can be the end-point. 123456 is a parameter and your code will return all the records having phoneNumber=123456.

Alternatively, the end-point can be `domain.com/api/records?phoneNumber=12345`.

Or Even, `domain.com/api/records/123456/phonenumber`.

The other option is to have the request data in the body and the domain would just look like `domain.com/api/records` with request as `{"PhoneNumber":"123456"}`

AFAIK, all these URLs respect REST protocol.

Comment: "get" in an url?

Comment: Yep, my bad. Edited. Thanks @sschrass

Comment: you are aware of that data in the body will not go together with GET-Requets?

Comment: Totally. I haven't specified type of call for any end-point. It is assumed that the body one will be of type POST. The intention of the question is to design the end-point.

Comment: the client don't know the phone number when he call my rest url.

Comment: Any of mine or @sschrass' end-point would suffice. All you have to do is to derive the phone number of the id in the request, find all the IDs (or records) and return.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like

```
/service/records/{id}/similar
```

where the service would define similarity. It depends on the usecases for when `Record` becomes more complex and the client should able to specify fields.
This would sooner or later result in queries that would not be based on an existing record and my look like

```
/service/records?foo=1&bar=2
```

I could also think of

```
/service/records/phone-number/12345
```

because you are really interested in records with the same `phoneNumber`, not similarity?

But again, as things get more complex you will be better off with a query I think.

Comment: the client don't know the phone number when he call my rest url.

Comment: sure he does! He just gets the record with the id he has.

Comment: In my use case, it's not really a phone number (i say it is for the example). It's some internal data he should'nt have access to, than we remove from the response.

Comment: ah I see, then I would go with the first url. As it is hidden to the client, only the service does know.